# PHP Table generation

Tags: php, php5

I have been using the following function (in the kohana html class in a table) to generate tables.

```
function table($columns,$reverse=false,$fill=false,array $attr=null){
    $c = '';
    //ugly hack, looking for fix
    $max=sizeof(max($columns));
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($columns);$i++){
            $column = $columns[$i];

        if($fill==true){
            $l = ($max-sizeof($column));
            for($ii=0;$ii<$l;$ii++){
                array_push($column,'');
            }
        }
        if($reverse==true){
            $columns[$i] = array_reverse($column);
        }else{
            $columns[$i] = $column;
        }
    }
    for($i=0,$l=sizeof($columns);$i<$l;$i++){
        $column = $columns[$i];
        $c.="<tr>";
        for($ii=0,$ll=sizeof($column);$ii<$ll;$ii++){
            $c.="<td>".$column[$ii]."</td>";
        }
        $c.="</tr>";
    }
    return "<table".html::attributes($attr).">".$c."</table>";
}
```

And then I have been calling it like so:

```
echo html::table(array(
    array('colunm 1 row 1','colunm 2 row 1'),
));
```

And a reversed table that auto fills the columns.

```
echo html::table(array(
    array('colunm 1 row 1','colunm 2 row 1'),
    array('column 1 row 2','column 2 row 2')
),true,true);
```

Comment: There's also [PEAR's HTML_Table](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Table) package, if you're into that sort of thing.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't test, but I would write it something like this:

```
function table($rows, $reverse = false, $fill = false, array $attr = null) {
    $c = '';
    $max_cols = sizeof(max($columns));

    foreach ($rows as $columns) {
        if ($fill && sizeof($columns) < $max_cols) {
            $columns = array_merge($columns, array_fill(0, $max_cols - sizeof($columns), ''));
        }
        if ($reverse) {
            $columns = array_reverse($columns);
        }
        $c .= '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $columns) . '</td></tr>';
    }

    return '<table>' . $c . '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Sweet, I wasn't aware of `array_fill` or `implode`.  Very convenient and it shortens the function by a lot.  There was one bug `$fill_to` should be `$max_cols`.  I decided to change some of the naming from `$columns` to `$rows`.  Here is the edited version: http://codepad.org/UQyynzqW Thanks.

Comment: that's what i get for not testing.  fixed the variable, and naming to make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

- Some of the variable names could benefit from being slightly less terse.
- Aren't you passing in an array of rows? Each element in the array is then an array of columns.
- What is max? Is it trying to find the row with the most columns? Either rename to something more self-documenting or add a comment.
- array_map may be worth a look and could feasibly allow for reverse to be replaced with a callback function.
- Consider changing the last lines of the function to:

  ```
  return "<table".html::attributes($attr).">".$c."</table>";
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking for the return statement. Or rather I wasn't thinking %).  Also, yes I'm passing in an array of rows which contains an array of columns.

Comment: Yes max is attempting to find the max number of columns.  Basically if you reverse a table with out all the rows having the same number of columns, the table will fill to the left.  By passing in true to `$fill` it adds additional empty cells to the end of table so it doesn't fill to the left.  What would you advise for a naming alternative to `$max`?  That's the php function name so I thought it was well suited.

Comment: Perhaps $max could be called $num_tbl_columns since it's the number of columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

replace for loops with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I would love to use foreach, but I am unsure how to use it in place of the first for loop.  I am reassigning itself as a reversed array at the end of the loop.  I don't believe php allows you to reassign the looping variable inside a foreach.

Comment: Actually, you can using foreach($array as $key => &$value)